# C# Issue when reading NET app.config values

Tags: c#, settings, user.config

I'm trying to read my saved configuration settings back into TextBoxes with

```
txtMailServer.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.MailServer;
```

But the text box contents are being prefixed with this text in front of the actual value...

> System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: **the.mail.server**

What is causing that?

Comment: How do you save it? What is the current value of the property if you inspect it with a debugger?

Comment: I doubt that it the actual code, also you might have something else you don't show here (unless that's the value you saved). Note: if you persist value using `txtMailServer.ToString()` then it's what you get...

Comment: I just noticed the extra text is being 'saved' into the .config
thanks for the idea. Will update...

Comment: Just don't _save_ with `txtMailServer.ToString()`, use `txtMailServer.Text` instead.

Answer (score 0):

OK FIXED - still learning...! 
I simply needed to tag .Text on the end of the control when I was saving it.
I made the assumption the Text attribute would be defaulted - not smart on my part.
D'oh